# A question about Fraenkel's 1922 paper

Tags: set-theory, notation

In [Fraenkel's 1922 paper](http://archive.org/stream/sitzungsberichte1922preu#page/252/mode/2up), what does the angle bracket mean that he uses on page 254 on line 3 in the expression $\phi(x) = \{\{\langle x \rangle, \langle o \rangle \}, \mathfrak U x+ \{\langle o\rangle\}\}$?

[image]

Comment: @oldrinb What are "elementary sets"?

Comment: Just guessing, but it seems to me as if it the third level of nested $\{$, after the "big" $\bigl\{$ and the normal sized $\{$.

Comment: @martini Oh wow, that never occurred to me but now that you point it out it does indeed seem plausible. And in fact, more than that: on the same page further down the interpretation you suggest would fit perfectly. Now if you would like to post your comment as an answer I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: @MattN. Did so.

Comment: I told you not to read the paper. It doesn't have any insights that you can't gain from Jech, or other modern expositions to permutations models. It only has difficult terminology and notation, as well the mistakes that were later uncovered by Mostowski.

Comment: I obviously don't listen to you.

Comment: ...until it's too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a guess, but it seems to me that $\langle\,\rangle$ is just the third level of nested set building braces $\{\,\}$, after the outmost "big" $\bigl\{\bigr\}$ and the second $\{\}$.

Comment: This is consistent with the way braces are used further down the same page, when describing $Z_o$.